# How to replace last letter to another letter in java using regular expression

Tags: java, regex, letter

i have seen to replace "," to "." by using ".$"|",$", but this logic is not working with alphabets. 
i need to replace last letter of a word to another letter for all word in string containing EXAMPLE_TEST using java
this is my code

```
  Pattern replace = Pattern.compile("n$");//here got the real problem
  matcher2 = replace.matcher(EXAMPLE_TEST);
  EXAMPLE_TEST=matcher2.replaceAll("k");
```

i also tried "//n$" ,"\n$" etc
Please help me to get the solution
input text=>njan ayman
output text=> njak aymak

Comment: there isn't a letter `n` at the last in your input. What's your input and expected output?

Comment: You should provide an example input/output and expected output. The way you put it: "last letter of a word to another letter for all word in string" it sounds that you want to replace any letter followed by a space: `(\w)(?=\s)`

Comment: String EXAMPLE_TEST="njan ayman"; it contain n

Comment: i expect  to print the out put "njak aymak"

Comment: @Ayman instead of putting the expected output in comments, put it in your actual question.

Comment: actually i already told the output read it carefully

Comment: but how to use this with Pattern, why this "n$" is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the end of string `$` anchor, use a [word boundary `\b`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

```
String s = "njan ayman";
s = s.replaceAll("n\\b", "k");
System.out.println(s); //=> "njak aymak"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use lookahead and group matching:

```
   String EXAMPLE_TEST = "njan ayman";
    s = EXAMPLE_TEST.replaceAll("(n)(?=\\s|$)", "k");
    System.out.println("s = " + s); // prints: s = njak aymak
```

**Explanation:**

```
(n) - the matched word character
(?=\\s|$) - which is followed by a space or at the end of the line (lookahead)
```

The above is only an example! if you want to switch every comma with a period the middle line should be changed to:

```
s = s.replaceAll("(,)(?=\\s|$)", "\\.");
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj it doesn't matter, the `n` was only an example, the OP said he tried switching a comma with a period which means he'll have to use: `s = s.replaceAll("(,)(?=\\s|$)", "\\.");`

Comment: Of course not. Again, the code above is an example, the OP will have to switch the expression in the matched group with what he wants: it could be `(,)`, `(n)`, `(\\w)` or whatever.

Comment: suppose how could i find n before spacing , actually i am trying to make  english to malayalam transilitration

Comment: @Ayman I don't understand your question: this answer demonstrates *exactly* it: how to spot `n` that comes before a whitespace.

Comment: @Nir Alfasi, I have a question which is close to this one, but I can't adopt the above code to mine.

I want to replace the last letter of a word, with anther one, when the last letter is 'c', and replace it by 'k' for example

input: 'George wants toc play football everyc dac' output: 'George wants tok play football everyk dak'

I am looking for a generalised code in order to replace other letter.

I tried to use replace, but this changes also this letter if it's exist in the middle of a word.

Comment: @George we don't need a regex for this task - we can go over each token (word), check the last character and replace it if it's 'c' with 'k'. This logic should be easy and very straightforward to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would set it up:

`(?=.\b)\w`

Which in Java would need to be escaped as following:

`(?=.\\b)\\w`

It translates to something like "a character (\w) after (?=) any single character (.) at the end of a word (\b)".

```
String s = "njan ayman aowkdwo wdonwan. wadawd,.. wadwdawd;";
s = s.replaceAll("(?=.\\b)\\w", "");
System.out.println(s); //nja ayma aowkdw wdonwa. wadaw,.. wadwdaw;
```

This removes the last character of all words, but leaves following non-alphanumeric characters. You can specify only specific characters to remove/replace by changing the `.` to something else.

However, the other answers are perfectly good and might achieve exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (word.endsWith("char oldletter")) {
    name = name.substring(0, name.length() - 1 "char newletter");
}
```

Comment: Would this even compile?